# JobSchedule.setOverrideDeadline works as periodical timer

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

Despite the documentation `setOverrideDeadline` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setOverrideDeadline(long)

this parameter works as timer task. I mean it wakes up the device each milliseconds delay.

```
int type = entity.getJobId();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PersistableBundle extras = new PersistableBundle();
            extras.putInt(A_.JOBSCHEDULER_TYPE, type);
            JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(type, new ComponentName(ctx, entity.getJobClass()))
                    .setMinimumLatency(nextTime - now)
                    .setOverrideDeadline(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60))
                    .setExtras(extras)
                    .build();
            JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                    (JobScheduler) ctx.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

if I use this `setOverrideDeadline(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60))` parameter the JobService wakes up repeatedly. Why?

On both Android 8.0 and Android 8.1

**EDIT**

Same behavior for both `jobFinished(jobParams, false)` and `jobFinished(jobParams, true)`

Comment: Can you post your job service code? You could be telling it to reschedule like with jobFinished(jobParams, true), instead of passing in false.

Comment: @SteveMiskovetz  Currently, I'm using `jobFinished(jobParams, false)`